# MSBuild with Azure - PublishProfileSet evaluates to a ""

Tags: c#, azure, msbuild, asp.net-mvc-4, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my project to Azure. I've been wrestling with EF code first on Azure for a few hours, but I got it to go once and it created a user. I went to publish an update, and now I'm getting the following error:

`Invoke build failed due to exception 'Expected "$(_PublishProfileSet)" to evaluate to a boolean instead of "", in condition "$(_PublishProfileSet) And '$(PublishProfileName)' =='' And '$(WebPublishProfileFile)'==''".`

I've removed the publish profile and readded it, I've also retrieved a fresh profile from Azure. This problem keeps popping up. I can't find PublishProfileSet in my solution anywhere, and I'm not sure where it's supposed to go or what it should be set to. Any ideas on how I can recover from this?

Comment: I can help u with this. Try the following, delete the folder Properties\Please blshProfiles. Rebuild the solution, then create a new publish profile. If that doesn't work and if u r able to share your solution shoot me an email sayedha@microsoft.com.

Comment: deleting the folder/rebuilding the solution did the trick, thanks Sayed!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per Sayed's comment, the solution was to delete  the entire `/Properties/PublishProfiles` directory in my solution, NOT to remove the Profiles from the "Edit Web Publish Profiles" window. The exact steps I took are as follows:

1. Delete the `/Properties/PublishProfiles` folder from my project.

   1.5. Restart Visual Studio.
2. Press F6 to rebuild the solution.
3. Downloaded a new copy of the profile from Azure.
4. Imported the profile through the Publish wizard.

Comment: I had a similar problem (not using Azure), and I needed step > 1.5) Restart Visual Studio