# Visual Studio 2013: Cannot Create MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, msbuild

When i'm trying to create an MVC app, or open exiting, but i got an error:

when creating new:

[image]

when opening:

> C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CinemaInformer\CinemaInformer\CinemaInformer.csproj : error  : Expected "$(_PublishProfileSet)" to evaluate to a boolean instead of "", in condition "$(_PublishProfileSet) And '$(PublishProfileName)' =='' And '$(WebPublishProfileFile)'==''".  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets

i got it after i've tried to open an MVC project for MVC 2.0 in VS2013. How can I fix it?
I got [this soultion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904822/msbuild-with-azure-publishprofileset-evaluates-to-a) for Azure, but i haven't this files to delete.

Comment: Re-install is your best bet.

Comment: Can you create ASP.Net(Web-Forms) applications?

Comment: @SaberAmani i dunno, i was able to launch console/wpf app, but I didn't check web forms before restoring previous state. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me after updating through Nuget the MVC version to 5, without having mvc 5 installed on the computer.

UPDATE: Installing [MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc5) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I should work, so i just restored previous Windows state from snapshot using Windows Recovery system, now it works.

Comment: hey Alex, can u elaborate your solution a little more?

Comment: I think i cannot, because i rolled back all changes done after checkpoint was created.

Comment: no problem. In case if you remember it or do it again, do post your experience/research/findings, it might just save somebodys life. Cheers!!

Comment: I have a project, that caused an error. I'l try to open it one VM, and if bug will reproduce, i'l send it to MS.